# Passing specific elements of UDT array to a function

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a UDT set up like this:

```
Public Type UserInfo
name as string
username as string
active_time as double
End Type
```

I then create an array of this type:

```
Dim list_of_users() as UserInfo
'Populate array here
```

What I want to do is pass the active_time values as an array into a separate function. Something like:

```
'StdDev function defined elsewhere    
standard_dev_all = StdDev(list_of_users().active_time)
```

Is this even possible? I suppose I could modify the function to deal with my UDT, but I have many more values than just active_time and it seemed like that would make it pretty messy.

Comment: I'd pass `by ref` the hole array list_of_users()

Comment: Great it worked for you. If it's what you were looking for I'd appreciate an upvote. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass it as

```
UDTvariable.Element
' or 
UDTvariable().Element
```

into a function. I mean,

1. the first one is not valid as the index of the array element (not the element's Element) hasn't been specified.
2. The second one is invalid as well.

The solution is to pass on to your function

```
Answer = Stdev(UDTVariable)
```

and inside the function, you do this

```
Function Stdev(ByRef UDTVariableTypeName UDTVariable)
    for i = 1 to N
        Something = UDTVariable(i).Element
        ' so on and so forth
    next i

    Stdev = SomeAnswer
End Function
```

You may omit writing `ByRef` as that is the default way of passing arguments, but I've kept it for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, that's what I kind of what I thought I'd have to do.